# Error: the program stops executing | Exit code: 255

Tags: c++

Could you tell me where did I fail? the program close when executing.

Before, it can finish the execution, but it didn't show me the results I was expecting. That's before, now it closes and didn't show me the results.

For example: if I needed the result of ***discount***, it shows me on the results a "***nan***", maybe there's the problem that didn't let it finish executing.

Now, as the title says, it didn't show me results but an exit code: 255.

However, if you go to an online compiler, paste the code, execute it and follow the instructions, you will see that at the end it doesn't show the results but an exit code: 139 Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I think the problem comes mainly from ***SalePrice()***,
Maybe I wrote it wrong or I'm missing libraries, I don't have that knowledge yet.

Sorry if I did not explain myself well, I am still learning and this had not happened to me before.

Thanks for reading untill here!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

class CarOnSale
{
private:
    string Brand;
    string Country;
    float Model;
    float ImportationCost;
public:
    //CONSTRUCTOR

    CarOnSale(string, string, float, float);

    //DESTRUCTOR

    ~CarOnSale();

    //SETTERS

    void setBrand(string);
    void setCountry(string);
    void setModel(float);
    void setImportationCost(float);

    //GETTERS

    string getBrand();
    string getCountry();
    float getModel();
    float getImportationCost();

    //ATTRIBUTES

    float Antiquity();
    float Discount();
    float Comission();
    float Taxes();
    float CompanyProfitPercentage();
    float SalePrice();
    float TotalPrice();
    string toString();

};


//CONSTRUCTOR CONSTRUCTOR CONSTRUCTOR

CarOnSale::CarOnSale(string pBrand, string pCountry, float pModel, float pImportationCost)
{
    Brand=pBrand;
    Country=pCountry;
    Model=pModel;
    ImportationCost=pImportationCost;
}
//DESTRUCTOR DESTRUCTOR DESTRUCTOR

CarOnSale::~CarOnSale()
{

}

//SETTER SETTER SETTER SETTER SETTER

void CarOnSale::setBrand(string pBrand)
{
    Brand=pBrand;
}

void CarOnSale::setCountry(string pCountry)
{
    Country=pCountry;
}

void CarOnSale::setModel(float pModel)
{
    Model=pModel;
}

void CarOnSale::setImportationCost(float pImportationCost)
{
    ImportationCost=pImportationCost;
}

//GETTER GETTER GETTER GETTER GETTER

string CarOnSale::getBrand()
{
    return(Brand);
}

string CarOnSale::getCountry()
{
    return(Country);
}

float CarOnSale::getModel()
{
    return(Model);
}

float CarOnSale::getImportationCost()
{
    return(ImportationCost);
}

//ATTRIBUTES ATTRIBUTES ATTRIBUTES ATTRIBUTES

float CarOnSale::Antiquity()
{
    float ActualYear=2019;

    return ActualYear-Model;
}

float CarOnSale::Discount()
{
    float Discount=0;

    if(Antiquity()>10)
    {
        return Discount=SalePrice()*0;
    }
    else
    {
        if(Antiquity()<10&&Antiquity()>5)
        {
            return Discount=SalePrice()*0.05;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Antiquity()<5)
            {
                return Discount=SalePrice()*0.015;
            }
        }
    }
}

float CarOnSale::Comission()
{
    float Comission=0;

    if(SalePrice()>8000000||Country=="USA"||Country=="Germany")
    {
        return Comission=ImportationCost*0.12;
    }
    else
    {
        return Comission=ImportationCost*0.06;
    }
}

float CarOnSale::Taxes()
{
    float Taxes=0;

    if(Country=="Germany")
    {
        return Taxes=SalePrice()*0.2;
    }
    else
    {
        if(Country=="Japan")
        {
            return Taxes=SalePrice()*0.3;
        }
        else
        {
            if(Country=="Italy")
            {
                return Taxes=SalePrice()*0.15;
            }
            else
            {
                if(Country=="USA")
                {
                    return Taxes=SalePrice()*0.08;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

float CarOnSale::CompanyProfitPercentage()
{
    float CompanyProfitPercentage=0;

    return CompanyProfitPercentage=ImportationCost*0.3;
}

float CarOnSale::SalePrice()
{
    float SalePrice=0;

    return SalePrice=ImportationCost+CompanyProfitPercentage()-Comission()-Discount()-Taxes();

}

float CarOnSale::TotalPrice()
{
    float TotalPrice=0;

    return TotalPrice=ImportationCost+CompanyProfitPercentage()-Comission()-Discount()-Taxes();

}

string CarOnSale::toString()
{
    stringstream s;

    s<<"Car is "<<Antiquity()<<" years old"<<endl;
    s<<"Discount: "<<Discount()<<" percent"<<endl;
    s<<"Car's comission: "<<Comission()<<endl;
    s<<"Car taxes: "<<Taxes()<<endl;
    s<<"Company Profit Percentage: "<<CompanyProfitPercentage()<<endl;
    s<<"Price of the car: "<<SalePrice()<<endl;

    return s.str();
}

int main()
{
    //Variables
    string BrandMAIN, CountryMAIN;
    float ModelMAIN, ImportationCostMAIN;


    //Object
    CarOnSale Car(BrandMAIN, CountryMAIN, ModelMAIN, ImportationCostMAIN);


    //Actions

    cout<<"Write your car's brand: "<<endl;
    cin>>BrandMAIN;

    cout<<"Write your car's country: "<<endl;
    cin>>CountryMAIN;

    cout<<"Write your car's model (year): "<<endl;
    cin>>ModelMAIN;

    cout<<"write your car's importation cost: "<<endl;
    cin>>ImportationCostMAIN;


    //SETTERS

    Car.setBrand(BrandMAIN);
    Car.setCountry(CountryMAIN);
    Car.setModel(ModelMAIN);
    Car.setImportationCost(ImportationCostMAIN);


    //Prints

    cout<<Car.toString();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hi, a segmentation fault is an illegal memory access. Perhaps run it under a debugger to find where it crashes?

Comment: In `CarOnSale::Taxes`, if `country` is "germany" the program does a couple bad things. It's not accepted and it results in the function not returning a value. Programs really hate it when they expect to receive a return value and don't get one. There is a similar problem in `CarOnSale::Comission`. In `CarOnSale::Comission`, `return Comission=ImportationCost*0.12;` almost certainly doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Look at your code, what happens to the discount if antiquity is exactly 5 or exactly 10?

Comment: This isn't an error but you're writing the same bad code over and over again, 
`float CarOnSale::CompanyProfitPercentage()
{
    float CompanyProfitPercentage=0;

    return CompanyProfitPercentage=ImportationCost*0.3;
}` can be written more simply as `float CarOnSale::CompanyProfitPercentage()
{
    return ImportationCost*0.3;
}` You don't need the `CompanyProfitPercentage` variable, you can do calculations without variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a recursive condition that is causing your stack to overflow. `Commision()` calls `SalePrice()` which in turn calls `Commision()`, etc. on and on.

Refactor your functions so that they don't recursively call each other.